# PrestaShop 1.7.8 API bug on simple product creation

Tags: php, prestashop, webapi, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to solve what seems to be again a PrestaShop bug.
Since I have an external management software for the store, the company who made it is using directly PS API to synchronize the e-commerce with the management.

Now,after some investigations, I've found this bug that, when creating a Simple Product (no combinations) through the relative API call, PrestaShop creates an empty record in the `product_attribute` table, which actually shouldn't be there for simple products without combinations.
This in fact messes up the product and other plugins which depend on a correct data-scheme.
I've checked all the xml attributes a schemes and they are all correct, but this record appears regardless.

Now, I've searched a bit and it seems to be a know problem, like you can see [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/17748), but I need a solution I can control, since the API request are not constructed by me but from the external management software.
A the end of that issue report you can fine a proposed workaround, but I don't understand how to implement it, since I need a fix for the PS core or WebService and cannot edit the requests made.

In short: i need to fix this bug without updating PS (which is due in some months).

Comment: Is your problem not related to this error
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/32884

(file to change: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/32884/files)

Comment: Yes, precisely, that's the fix I was searching for, but couldn't find the commit. Thank you.

Comment: Just manually change the file in the same location as the second link provided and reset your cache